# How to change button styles on press?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, font-awesome

In react-native project I have next button:

```
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';

<Icon.Button
            name='chevron-down'
            backgroundColor='transparent'
            color='#000000'
            padding={0}
            size={30}
            onPress={() => setIsCollapsed(false)}
        />
```

Everything is fine except one thing - on button press for a fraction of a second, appears black square round the button element. How can I remove this styling element?

Comment: Could be due to a border, try adding `border:0` and see what happens

Comment: if you need css verison, use [`button:active`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active)

Comment: @WebbH does not work

Comment: @bogdanoff I'm using styled-components

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap it inside TouchableOpacity and pass onPress method on touchable opacity's  onPress props

Example :

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setIsCollapsed(false)} >
    <Icon.Button
        name='chevron-down'
        backgroundColor='transparent'
        color='#000000'
        padding={0}
        size={30}
    />
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: unfortunately after wrapping  onPress does not work

Comment: Try to user Icon only instead of Icon.Button